Possible to protect formulae in Gsheet table columns and also allow editors to add new rows?
My Gsheet has a table into which users of the shared spreadsheet add rows throughout the day. It is formatted as a table so that when they add a new row at bottom the formulae in certain columns copy down. Most columns are populated by user (e.g., text type in, dropdown) but others have formulae that use VLOOKUP to display a name based on an ID in another sheet, display something if there is an error in one of the manually edited columns, etc. I would like to protect these columns so that the formulae can't be deleted or overwritten.
Without any data protection at the column level this works fine, users can add a row, and formulae copy to the new row. But users can alter cells with the formulae.
If I protect the columns so the authorized shared users cannot edit, then Sheets won't let them add a new row.
Anyone have a solution? Thanks!
I tried protecting one column as a test. Protection works, add new row does not. I hoped add new row would be allowed.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us better understand your problem, please provide a publicly accessible sample sheet with sample data and the desired result.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
